# Information used for prior updating

Tags: bayesian, generalized-linear-model, logit

Suppose that we have the following model

$logit(p[i])=a_{0}+a_{1}x_{i}$ with $i=1,2$ and $x_{0}=0 ,x_{1}=1$ and we want to use bayesian inference so we have to use priors for $a_{0},a_{1}$

And we are given the information that $p[1]\simeq =0.5$.So my idea in order to plug this information in bayesian inference is the following:

$$logit(p[1])=a_{0}\Rightarrow \frac{p[1]}{1-p[1]}=a_{0}=1$$

So if $a_{0}$ had for prior a Normal distribution ,with the previous knowledge now will be $a_{0}\sim norm(1,\sigma^2)$

Is my assumption correct ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vague item of information that $p[1]\approx 1/2$ is an item of prior information on $$a_0+0\times a_1=a_0$$which may be turned into a prior mean on $a_0$ by$$0=\text{logit}(1/2)\approx\text{logit}(p[1])=a_0$$that is, an assumption that the prior mean of $a_0$ is $0$.

Comment: ,I was also thinking if there is a way to change the variance of $a_{0}$ distribution based on the new information.For instance if we calculate the C.I. for $logit(p[1])$ we will have some information about the range of $a_{0}$.